# increase the width of input box? Removing black outline that comes when button or input box is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**How to increase the width of input box? I tried focus method(in css) but nothing changed, I am also having difficulty in removing black outline that comes when button or input box is clicked?**

### Code I tried -

```css
input:focus{
width: 40%;
    }
.btn{
  border:1px solid rgb(125, 8, 184);
        color:rgb(125, 8, 184);
        background: rgba(218, 154, 248, 0.247);
        font-size: 16px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="left" style="padding: 7% 6% 4% 37%;">
            <input type="text" value="" style="background-color: rgba(253, 253, 253, 0.329);border: 0; font-size: 16px; width: 25%; border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(125, 8, 184); "><button style="right : 0; " class="btn ">Search</button>
        </div>
```

style="background-color: rgba(253, 253, 253,0.329);
border: 0; font-size: 16px; width: 25%; border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(125, 8, 184); ">Search

Answer (score 0):

outline: none; can solve your problem there, but is better if you can keep the outline (due the accesibility for those who need)

as mentioned before seens like your width is working, did you put the correct class at your css file?

more about outline Accessibility can be find here:

https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#navigation-mechanisms-focus-visible